# Refactoring boilerplate type constraints

Tags: scala

I have an object with a bunch of related routines and all their declarations look the same, something like

```
object Sorting {
  def qsort[a <% Ordered[a]] ....

  def partition[a <% Ordered[a]] ...

  def qselect[a <% Ordered[a]] ...
}
```

Is there a way to specify the type constraint in one place and reduce declarations to something like `qsort[a](xs: Stream[a])` or even better just `qsort(xs: Stream[a])` ?

For the time being I've decided to roll with implicit classes

```
object Implicits {
  implicit class SortableArray[a <% Ordered[a]](xs: Array[a]) {
    def qsort = {...}
  }
}

object Application {
  import Implicits._
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val xs = Array(1,2,3)
    xs.qsort
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not declare type as `type U[T] = T <% Ordered[T]`.  This will not work and even will not compile.

### But, there are some workarounds you can apply to your code

Confider this think-flow:

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds):

`def f[A <% B](a: A) = a.bMethod`

is the same as

`def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => B) = a.bMethod`

and this

`def g[A : B](a: A) = h(a)`

is the same as

`def g[A](a: A)(implicit ev: B[A]) = h(a)`
.

So going back to you example:

```
def qsort[A <% Ordered[A]] = ???
```

... is translated to:

```
def qsort[A](implicit ev: A => Ordered[A]) = ???
```

... now you can introduce type parameter like:

```
type O[A] = A => Ordered[A]
```

... and use it as:

```
def gsort[A] (implicit ev: O[A])
```

... which can be simplified into:

```
def gsortX[A : O]
```

Then all your code you can write as:

**Before**

```
object Sorting {

  def qsort[A <% Ordered[A]] = ???

  def partition[A <% Ordered[A]] = ???

  def qselect[A <% Ordered[A]] = ???
}
```

**After**

```
object Sorting {

  type O[A] = A => Ordered[A]

  def qsort[A: O] = ???

  def partition[A: O] = ???

  def qselect[A: O] = ???
}
```

**Or even better using trait**

```
trait Sorting[A] {
  type O = A => Ordered[A]
  implicit def f : O

  def qsort = ???

  def partition = ???

  def qselect = ???
}
```

I hope this helps somehow :)

Comment: It seems to work fine with object but how should I use the trait? Extending some object with `object IntSorting extends Sorting[Int]` kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Synapse,
You can use pimp my library approach as well, but then you must create implicit wrapper with similar method as in trait:
`implicit def toPimp[A](xs: Stream[A]) = new { def qsort[A](xs:Stream[A]) = new Sorting[A](xs: Stream[A]) {...}.sort(xs)}` and then you can use it
`xs.sort`.

Comment: He could also use `Ordering` instead of `Ordered`, which would obviate the need for the view bound.

Answer (score 1):

Not with an alias, as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680630/use-context-bound-in-type-alias). That view bound actually adds an implicit parameter to each of those methods, which isn't easily abstracted into a type alias.