# ClassTag for type class parameter

Tags: scala, types

I want to create a type class that will constrain its defined abstract type to have a `ClassTag`. Here is a simplified example:

```
trait A[T] {
  type B <: Z

  val tag = implicitly[ClassTag[B]]
}

// Error:(8, 24) No ClassTag available for A.this.B
//  val tag = implicitly[ClassTag[B]]
                  ^
```

I need `B` to have a `ClassTag[B]` and I can't define `A` like `trait A[T, B: ClassTag]` because I want `A` be implicitly available for `T`, like in `def foo[T: A](t: T)`. `B` also has to be upper-bound to some `Z`, but it seems to make no difference.

Is there a way to express `ClassTag` constraint on `B`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680630/use-context-bound-in-type-alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way for the compiler to provide you with a `ClassTag` here, as it has no clue what `B` might end up being.

Make it an abstract `def` instead, and let the concrete implementation of `A` provide it:

```
trait A[T] {
  type B <: Z
  def tag: ClassTag[B] // you may want to declare it as implicit
}
```

and, for instance,

```
new A[Int] {
  type B = Z
  def tag = implicitly
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. Thought I was missing some other way.